# How to back up multiple databases to seperate files with one command

Tags: sql, bash, backup, web-hosting, database-backups

Hey all, we have 2 web servers which may go offline Friday. we have ~90 websites hosted on these servers and I already have found a way to backup each website folder to its own .tar.gz file - what I need now is to find a way to export each database from our database server as its own SQL backup with one command.

Currently the only way I know how is to use PHP myAdmin, but for 100+ databases that gets a little tedious.

Is there a simple way to export each database as its own SQL backup file over SSH?

Comment: 100+ databases with no existing backup strategy in place that you could leverage for this exercise? {shudder}

Comment: I walked into a job where our server admin can't backup a single file - forget that he can't even shut down a server over SSH even with a step-by-step cheat sheet. I'm a trained graphic designer but if our servers might be going down I'm trying to do whatever I can to save data because we currently have no backups other than what I've done by hand site-by-site in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `mysqldump --all-databases` but you'll get only one big SQL dump.

Found this bash script:

```
for T in `mysql -N -B -e 'show databases' -pYOUR_ROOT_PASSWORD`; 
   do echo $T; 
   mysqldump -pYOUR_ROOT_PASSWORD $T | gzip -c > $T.sql.gz;
done
```

You just have to test it and adapt the path/names to your needs.

Comment: yeah, I want to evnetually sort these  into folders with database(s) backup files and .tar.gz of each website so they can be distributed to clients if needed. Having one big file isn't bad for us to restore to a server, but I don't want to give each client the data and passwords of each of our other clients in addition to their own data…

Comment: I've been fighting with it and the best I can get is: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Comment: aha! success, I got it to work finally, but I had to add username and password to both lines there, thanks a ton man!

Comment: Ah yeah, if your user is not root, then you need to specify it in the options. Glad it finally worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "Provide MySQL root password as argument.";
    exit;
fi
cnt=0
for T in `mysql -N -B -e 'show databases' -u root -p$1`; 
   do
   D=`date "+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S"`;
   cnt=$((cnt + 1))
   File=$T"_"$D;
   echo "Backing up $T to $File.sql.gz"; 
   mysqldump -u root -p$1 $T | gzip -c > $File.sql.gz;
   echo "Done.";
done

echo "$cnt databases backed up.";
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is suitable for shared hosting servers, it stores every backup in respective users home folder, so that they can restore/use/remove them accordingly.

```
backup_folder="automated_backup/";


if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "Provide MySQL root password as argument.";
    exit;
fi
cnt=0
for T in `mysql -N -B -e 'show databases' -u root -p$1`; 
   do
   D=`date "+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S"`;
   cnt=$((cnt + 1))
   User=`echo $T | cut -d'_' -f 1`
   Folder="/home/$User/";
   Folder2=$Folder$backup_folder;
   if [ -d "$Folder" ]; then
      if [ ! -d "$Folder2" ]; then

        echo "$Folder2 not exists, creating it …";
        mkdir -p $Folder2

      fi
      File=$Folder2$T"_"$D;
      echo "Backing up $T to $File.sql.gz"; 
      mysqldump -u root -p$1 $T | gzip -c > $File.sql.gz;
      chown $User.$User -R $Folder2;
      echo "Done.";
   fi   
done

echo "$cnt databases backed up.";
```